# How to create connectivity between Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP client

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003

On virtual PC I have installed Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP.

I created a domain on Windows Server 2003 and I want to add domain on Windows XP. How to do this process?

Comment: please elaborate a little more

Answer (score 1):

You need Windows XP Professional.

From http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sysdm_ident_join_domain.mspx?mfr=true:

> You must be logged on as an administrator or a member of the Administrators group in order to complete this procedure. If your computer is connected to a network, network policy settings may also prevent you from completing this procedure.
>
> 1. Open System in Control Panel.
> 2. On the Computer Name tab, click Change.
> 3. Under Member of, click Domain, type the name of the domain
>      you want to join, and then click OK.  You will be prompted to
>      provide a user name and user password to join the computer to the
>      domain.
> 4. Click OK to close the System Properties dialog box.
>      You will be prompted to restart your computer to apply your changes.